# To put colour at diffeent rectangle part of image when button clicked HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html5-canvas, imagemap

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="exscript.js"></script>

      <body>
      <p> 
        <div class="buttons">
        <input type = "button" style="background-color:lightgreen" value="PjM ECU" onclick="PjMECU()">
        <input type = "button" style="background-color:lightgreen" value="SW SD" onclick="Swsd()">
        <input type = "button" style="background-color:lightgreen" value="SW PD" onclick="Swpd()">
        <input type = "button" style="background-color:lightgreen" value="image view" onclick="imgview()">
        </div>
        </button>       
        </li>
        <li>
            <p dir="ltr">
                <img src="ajay1.png" id="StaticView" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 1019px; height: 742px;" title="Static View picture" usemap="#StaticView" /></p>
            <p dir="ltr"> 
            <map name="StaticView"> 
                    <area coords="16,242,76,304" href="" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="16,242,60,62" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="934,362,76,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="91,314,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="161,250,69,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="709,641,76,62" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="706,421,73,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="511,514,81,59" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="706,367,72,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="857,373,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="858,315,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="858,256,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="793,314,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="792,256,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="617,307,70,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="247,412,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="410,576,80,58" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="322,669,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="321,615,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="321,560,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="229,511,71,116" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  
    <area coords="898,90,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="453,247,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="385,413,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="384,358,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="934,309,75,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="934,256,76,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="704,260,74,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="386,303,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="932,420,79,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="623,38,60,54" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="16,204,60,97" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="22,119,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="22,68,60,97" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" /> 
    <area coords="18,34,71,136" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="457,33,60,62" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="617,425,76,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="617,371,74,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="535,371,75,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="315,357,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="543,308,64,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="617,247,69,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="543,249,64,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="961,31,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="898,31,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="315,302,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="313,246,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="386,32,60,131" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="408,510,82,56" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="316,413,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="247,357,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="536,207,158,156" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" /> 
    <area coords="706,313,73,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="704,203,75,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="624,104,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="789,205,136,263" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" /> 
    <area coords="714,573,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="318,509,79,217" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  
    <area coords="168,38,69,127" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="385,247,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="247,246,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="248,303,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="243,204,274,263" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" /> 
    <area coords="930,205,91,210" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  
    <area coords="694,38,60,114" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="247,33,129,128" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  
    <area coords="99,108,60,52" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="705,510,80,120" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  
    <area coords="624,644,72,59" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="122,510,95,115" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  
    <area coords="21,511,90,114" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="165,314,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />   
    <area coords="89,250,60,49" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />    
    <area coords="622,509,74,126" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  
    <area coords="84,203,150,263" href="?section=" shape="rect" target="_blank" />  

    </map></p>

    </p>
            <canvas id="view1"></canvas> <!--for API View-->
            <canvas id="view2"></canvas>    <!--for Statik View-->  
        </body>
    </html>
```

// the above is my code and now the javascript :
      the final image has to be generated using the javascript. get the image from the source and some part of rectangle colour has to be changed to white( in the sense i should not see some image part and download the image in any format)

```
    function imgview()
    {
    var canvas  = document.getElementById("view1");

                if(canvas.getContext)
                {
        var context_Context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var img  = document.getElementById("StaticView");
            var img_Context = img.getContext("2d");

                canvas.width  = 1019;
                canvas.height = 742;

        context_Context.clearRect(706,367,778,416);

        //image1 = new Image();
        //image1.src = "ajay1.png";



        //image1.addEventListener('load', drawImage1);

        //context.drawImage(image1, 10, 10);

                //canvas_Context.font="25px Georgia";
                //canvas_Context.fillText("ROLE TWO!",350,250);   // to fill text

                var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
                window.open(dataUrl, "toDataURL() image", "width=1019, height=742");
                Window.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>"); 
                }

    }

here i need:
with the help of area cordis i want some of image part to hide or clear that area but not the whole image.
1) clear the rectangle and diaplay the final image as .jpeg or
2) change the colour of the image and display the final image as .jpeg
```

Comment: Dude fix the question, add a fiddle/code snippet instead of throwing the code like this

Comment: This question is too big, in every sense of the word. Be technically specific, nobody will want to read all that just help with trivial javascript problems.

Comment: any how sorry i am new to this site .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have found solution to this:
1) use a button: 
<input type = "button" style="background-color:lightgreen" value="name" onclick="name()">
2) use an canvas element with id :
 <canvas id="view1"></canvas>
3) image with image ID

then in Javascript::::
function name()
{`

var canvas = document.getElementById("view1");

        if(canvas.getContext) 
        {
            var canvas_Context=canvas.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("image id");

            canvas.width  = 1248;
            canvas.height = 763;
            canvas_Context.drawImage(img,0,0); 
            canvas_Context.fillStyle = 'White';

            //code for Role name : put the the (X1,Y1,width,Height)

canvas_Context.fillRect(1127,329,116,63)    


canvas_Context.fillRect(936,366,82,55)  
canvas_Context.fillRect(93,318,66,55)   


       }
}
```